# Why does my Validare Zip Code(boolean) program return false?

Tags: java, computer-science

The instruction to the program is: Zip codes consist of 5 consecutive digits. Prompt the user for a five digit zip code as a String. Create a Java method called isValid and pass the String as a parameter to the method. In the method determine whether the input is a valid zip code. A valid zip code is as follows:
Must only contain numbers (no non-digits allowed).
Must not contain any spaces.
Must not be greater than 5 digits in length.
If the zip code is valid return true to the main method, else return false.

Everytime I put in a valid zip code it still says false

this is my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println ("Enter a zip code: ");
    String zipCode = input.nextLine ();

      System.out.println (isValid (zipCode));
  }
  public static boolean isValid (String zipCode)
  {
    boolean yes = false;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < zipCode.length (); i++)
      {
    
    int digit = zipCode.charAt (i);
    //if only contains number
    if (digit > 48 && digit < 57)
      {
        System.out.println (digit);
      }
    else
      {
        return false;
      }

    int len = zipCode.length ();
    if (len == 4)
      {
        System.out.println (len);
      }
    else
      {
        return false;
      }

      }
    return yes;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include both 0 and 9 , Hence, please change this line

```
if (digit > 48 && digit < 57)
```

to

```
if (digit >= 48 && digit <= 57)
```

On the other hand, the length of a zip should be 5 instead of 4, Hence, please change this line:

```
if (len == 4)
```

to

```
if (len == 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor the code and use a matcher in order to reduce the validations.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a zip code: ");
        String zipCode = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println(isValid(zipCode));
    }

    public static boolean isValid(String zipCode) {
        boolean yes = false;
        // Check that only digits are accepted and the length is equals to 4
        if (zipCode.matches("[0-9]+") && zipCode.length() == 4) {
            yes = true;
        }
        return yes;
    }
}
```

Comment: The instructor likely knows by inference that the OP does not know regex yet

Comment: Sorry, I offered an alternative because the question not mention any constraint about how resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> boolean yes = false;
> return yes;
> ```

> ```
> if (len == 4) {
> ...
> } else {
>    return false;
> }
> ```

Your two specific mistakes.

More generally, you need to learn how to debug. Eventually you'll get some basic skill in eyeballing errors, but only the most simple errors are eyeballable. (It's surely a word, no?)

Take out pen and paper if you have to, but the name of the game is: You calculate what you think the code should do in your head. Then you let the computer do it and compare notes: What should *every* variable be, what is the result of every call? Crosscheck with what you think. Where you and computer disagree? Bug.

Then it's just a matter of picking some inputs and off you go. A debugger makes this a lot simpler, but some `System.out.println` statements and some sweat will take care of it too.

Do that next time instead of asking on SO. It's good exercise, and you'll never be worth a can of beans as a programmer if you can't do this.